# Sencha Touch 2 change rootproperty of store

Tags: extjs, touch, store

I have a form with several dropdown menu's (selectfields) and a store with several arrays. How can i set a different rootproperty for each selectfield?

Is there a way to use data.quality for one selectfield and data.quantity for another?

I could make six different stores but the only difference would be the rootproperty and i rather fire one larger ajax request than six small ones.It would also mean less code and less files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand exactly what you want... An alternative is to use [Ext.Ajax.request()](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.Ajax) and get all the data then load the necessary data to each selectfield using `selectfield.setOptions()`

Hope it helps...